# React: toDateString - if date 1 is < date 2 not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a simple date compare.

If date 1 is less than date 2 then show something.

I have the following:

```
const bltrip = new Date(item.DateTo.toDate()).toDateString();
const todaysdate = new Date().toDateString();
```

This returns:

```
Thu, 31 Dec 2022 00:01:00 GMT and Tue, 10 Oct 2023 12:37:33 GMT
```

I then run:

```
{bltrip < todaysdate ? 'yes' : 'no'}
```

But everytime this returns yes? Even if bltrip is a date in the future - what am I missing?

Comment: You are comparing two strings lexicographically. `h` comes before `u` and hence `'Thu' < 'Tue'` is `true`; the rest of the letters are irrelevant. Perhaps the same applied to other cases you got.

Comment: Just drop the `.toDateString()`?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to compare date in ISOString.

```js
const bltrip = new Date(item.DateTo).toISOString();
const todaysdate = new Date().toISOString();

{bltrip < todaysdate ? 'yes' : 'no'}
```